# Application of fermats little theorem.

Tags: number-theory

Use Fermats little theorem to show that if p is a prime and $x^{p-1} +y^{p-1} = z^{p-1} $, then $ p|xyz $

i have no idea where to start other than assuming that x,y,z are integers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $x,y,z$ are not zero, $x^{p-1}=y^{p-1}=z^{p-1}=1$ mod $p$ this implies that $1+1=1$ mod $p$ impossible.

Comment: so one of em is going to have to be zero so $ p|xyz $ as $xyz=0 $

Answer (score 1):

Fermat’s little theorem states that
$$
a^{p-1} =1 ~(mod~p)
$$
if $a \ne 0 ~(mod ~p)$. Well one of those three expressions must be zero modulo $p$.  Hence $p$ must divide $x$ or $y$ or $z$. So it definitely divides $xyz$.